# Recommendation for SWT/JFace Javascript Editor?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, editor, swt, jface

I'm building an app using SWT + JFace and I would like to integrate a Javascript editor (with Syntax Highlighting and Auto-Indent).

I'm looking for something simple like [RSyntaxTextArea](http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/):  just use the widget like as a TextArea and set the syntax to "Javascript".

So far I've come across examples with "JFace Text" but it seems I have to implement the Javascript part myself. Also, I don't want to integrate the whole Eclipse workbench if possible.

Do you know of any component that would do the job?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use StyledText widget (so no dependency on JFace) to show syntax highlight (see [Into the Deep End of the SWT StyledText Widget](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/StyledText%202/article2.html)), but it's quite lot of work to do..
For additional example see [Implements syntax coloring using the StyledText API](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/ImplementssyntaxcoloringusingtheStyledTextAPI.htm).

It's also possible to use [SWT_AWT bridge](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html) and put the RSyntaxTextArea to your application directly..

Answer (score 2):

I found some interesting project, which might help you with the situation..

It's called [The DJ Project](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/sweet/index.html) (The Sweet library brings some rich components to SWT-based applications) and when you [check the Gallery](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/sweet/screenshots/index.html), you can find as [last example SWT gui with javascript syntax highlighted text area](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/sweet/screenshots/images/SyntaxHighlighter.png).

The licence is LGPL, which is one of the best for any purpose..